# #f output for scheme result inside repl.it

Tags: scheme, lisp, replit

I'm doing some problems from [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)

My case outputs #f as a valid result in the repl.it interpreter. I'm applying (and (not (max a b c)) (not (min a b c))) to get mid value.

I've tried rearranging the values for the mid function. The max and min functions work alright.

```lisp
(define (max a b c) 
(cond 
  ((and(>= a b)(>= a c)) a)
  ((and(>= b a)(>= b c)) b)
  ((and(>= c a)(>= c b)) c)
))

(define (min a b c) 
(cond 
  ((and(<= a b)(<= a c)) a)
  ((and(<= b a)(<= b c)) b)
  ((and(<= c a)(<= c b)) c)
))

(define (mid a b c)
(and 
  (not (max a b c)) 
  (not (min a b c))
))

(mid 10 8 6)
```

The output in the repl.it scheme interpreter is:

```lisp
=> #f
```

I'd expect an error of some sort or a number value but this code returns a green #f so I'm assuming it means something is false? How can I fix this code to return a mid using conditional expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's worth thinking about how many tests you have to do to compute these things: to compute the extremum of three elements under any ordering operator you need to do no more than three comparisons:

```
(define (extremum/3 ordered? a b c)
  ;; find the extremum of three elements under ordered?
  (cond ((and (ordered? a b) (ordered? a c)) a)
        ((ordered? b c) b)
        (else c)))
```

And given this general function you can now define max/3 and min/3 easily:

```
(define (max/3 a b c)
  (extremum/3 >= a b c))

(define (min/3 a b c)
  (extremum/3 <= a b c))
```

Computing the mid point of three elements also requires no more than three tests:

```
(define (mid/3 a b c)
  (if (>= a b)
      (if (>= a c)
          ;; a is greatest, so we need to pick b or c
          (if (>= b c) b c)
          ;; a is the mid point
          a)
      (if (>= a c)
          ;; a is the mid point
          a
          ;; a is the minimum, pick b or c
          (if (>= c b) b c))))
```

It's interesting to consider how many comparisons you need to find the mid point of n items.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was passing a NOT from max AND min which is why it was evaluating false every time since there's always a false result from those expressions. I continued using comparisons to get the correct solution and adjusted the exceptions to take the mid to be a value which is either repeated three times or twice if it's not less than max or greater than min. The only thing that is unsettling is that I had to essentially express all conditions that are valid to isolate a mid number and couldn't explicitly define mid as NOT the max number AND NOT the min number. That being said there's got to be a better way to reduce these functions and eliminate the bulk of the comparisons...

```lisp
(define (mid a b c) 
(cond 
  ((and(< a (max a b c))(> a (min a b c))) a)
  ((and(< b (max a b c))(> b (min a b c))) b)
  ((and(< c (max a b c))(> c (min a b c))) c)
  (else (cond
    ((= (min a b c) (max a b c)) a)
    ((= a b) a)
    ((= a c) a)
    ((= b c) b)
))
))
```